# How to return the sum of a for statement within a method

Tags: java

I am trying to write code that sums up the total of what the dice rolls (don't worry about the output of dice[i], I just need to return the sum).

```
public static int displayAndTotalDice(int[] dice) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Dice " + i + " rolls: " + dice[i]);
            int sum = 0 + dice[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I get the error "sum cannot be resolved to a variable." Any suggestions?

Comment: `sum` is only in scope in the `for` loop. Move the deceleration outside of the `for` loop and it'll work. (`int sum = 0; for(int i = 0;...`)

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`sum` should be scoped (and initialized) so that it is reachable after your loop.

```
public static int displayAndTotalDice(int[] dice) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Dice " + i + " rolls: " + dice[i]);
        sum += dice[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of the `sum` variable into the method-level scope before using it in the `for` loop and returning its value.

You are getting the *error* **"sum cannot be resolved to a variable."** because you declared `sum` within the `for` loop and so only visible within the loop.

```
public static int displayAndTotalDice(int[] dice) {
        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Dice " + i + " rolls: " + dice[i]);
            sum += dice[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```